# Prevent Android app from opening Fake Camera

Tags: java, android, kotlin, camera

[image]

We have an Android app, that supports clicking pics using Camera only and not gallery. However certain 3rd party apps like Gallery Cam or Fake Camera apps, prevent this from happening by modifying the source of camera control from camera to gallery, so the user is able to choose pic from gallery. This defeats the purpose of the app. Looking for suggestions to prevent the same by prompting the user if the pic is not captured from the camera

Answer (score 3):

> We have an Android app, that supports clicking pics using Camera only and not gallery

My guess, from this statement and the screenshot, is that you are using `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` to get the picture. If so, the user is welcome to use whatever they want that supports `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, and that does not have to be a camera app.

If you want to force the use of a camera, take the picture yourself, using CameraX, a third-party camera library, or platform APIs directly (e.g., Camera2).

Comment: Yeah, by using implicit intents you're basically asking the system to request a handler for that action, and any app that claims to support it can be given that responsibility, and it can do whatever it likes. If you want full control over that action, you can't hand it off to the system like that by using an implicit intent (i.e. one where you don't specify which app is going to handle it)